ProgrammingError: relation "users_customuser" does not exist
I have created a custom user as follows:
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    USERNAME_FIELD="email"
    REQUIRED_FIELDS=["username"]
    
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.email

I have defined the model in my settings.py file as follows
AUTH_USER_MODEL = "users.CustomUser"
when I run the migrate command I get the above error
I have tried running python manage.py migrate users --fake but the error still persists
Internal Server Error: /api/register/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 105, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "users_customuser" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT 1 AS "a" FROM "users_customuser" WHERE "users_customu...
                             ^
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 65, in _view_wrapper
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 104, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/app/apps/users/views.py", line 15, in post
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 227, in is_valid
    self._validated_data = self.run_validation(self.initial_data)
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 426, in run_validation
    value = self.to_internal_value(data)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 483, in to_internal_value
    validated_value = field.run_validation(primitive_value)
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rest_framework/fields.py", line 751, in run_validation
    return super().run_validation(data)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rest_framework/fields.py", line 548, in run_validation
    self.run_validators(value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rest_framework/fields.py", line 560, in run_validators
    validator(value, self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rest_framework/validators.py", line 73, in __call__
    if qs_exists(queryset):
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rest_framework/validators.py", line 21, in qs_exists
    return queryset.exists()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1288, in exists
    return self.query.has_results(using=self.db)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 659, in has_results
    return compiler.has_results()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1530, in has_results
    return bool(self.execute_sql(SINGLE))
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1562, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 122, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 79, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 92, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 100, in _execute
    with self.db.wrap_database_errors:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 91, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 105, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "users_customuser" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT 1 AS "a" FROM "users_customuser" WHERE "users_customu...
                             ^

what could I be doing wrong ?

Did you run makemigrations before?

Yes. I have made migrations

Follow steps:

delete migrations folder
delete database db.sqlite3
run command python manage.py makemigrations your_app_name
run command python manage.py migrate

